# Download automatically a file(.sql) in wwwroot using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So far here what i've tried it can download the sql file but it is empty

```
//test.php

 <?php
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=wordpress_db1.sql');
?>
```

Here is what my root folder look like

[image]

I want to download the wordpress_db1.sql file when I run the test.php but I always get empty on it. How can I fix this? thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Export MySQL database using PHP only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22195493/export-mysql-database-using-php-only)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the headers doesn't read the file.  You can name the file anything you want in the attachment.  You have to actually emit the file:

```
readfile('wordpress_db1.sql');
```

Comment: If you add it then it should work as you expect assuming the php file is in the same directory

Answer (score 7):

Below code will do the trick for you.

```
<?php 
$file_name = 'file.sql';
$file_url = 'http://www.example.com/' . $file_name;
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\""); 
readfile($file_url);
?>
```

**What have you gone wrong** is  `readfile($file_url);`. Setting headers will not get the job done. you have use  `readfile($file_url);`

Comment: is says failed to open stream why is that?

Comment: can you post the exact error here. can be due to the path is not correct and watch out for the permission too