# We want to copy and paste all tables from one database to another database using php

Tags: php

We have two databases. First one connected in local machine and another one connected in global server. Now i want to copy and paste all tables from local server to global server. How can i copy and paste tables using php code.

Comment: No i need to copy and paste tables using php code when i submit button

Comment: just use [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html), much faster

Comment: Sorry i don't have shell access

Answer (score -1):

Try examples from:

[Export MySQL database using PHP only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22195493/export-mysql-database-using-php-only)

Comment: how about properly crediting the author